# using str.format() and a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Why does this work:

```
data = {'first': 'Hodor', 'last': 'Hodor!'}
print('{first} {last}'.format(**data))
```

and this works:

```
bdays = {
    'Wesley Neill': 'January 6, 1985',
    'Victoria Neill': 'August 25, 1992',
    'Heather Neill': 'June 25, 1964'
}

print('\n {} \n {} \n {}'.format(*bdays))
```

But this does not work:

```
 print('\n {} \n {} \n {}'.format(**bdays))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wesle/PycharmProjects/practicepython/birthdays.py", line 9, in <module>
    print('We have the following names in our dictionary: \n {} \n {} \n {} \n'.format(**bdays))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The first example has the dictionary keys in the placeholder braces and uses **kwargs in the argument.

The second does not have keys, and only has one asterisk in the .format() argument.

The third has no keys in the placeholders, as in example 1, but it does use **kwargs in the argument.

I see what I need to do to make things work, but I'm curious about the subtleties here.

Comment: Iterating through a dict gives the keys only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what the asterisk notation does:

```
**dict is equivalent to k1=v1, k2=v, ...
*dict is equivalent to [k1, k2, ...]
```

So you're doing:

```
# This print('{first} {last}'.format(**data)) is:
print('{first} {last}'.format(first='Hodor', last='Hodor!'))

# This print('\n {} \n {} \n {}'.format(*bdays)) is:
print('\n {} \n {} \n {}'.format(['Wesley Neill', 'Victoria Neill', 'Heather Neill']))

# This print('\n {} \n {} \n {}'.format(**bdays)) is:
print('\n {} \n {} \n {}'.format('Wesley Neill'='January 6, 1985', 'Victoria Neill'='August 25, 1992', 'Heather Neill'='June 25, 1964'))
```

There are no keys stated in the final format string so you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

`.format(**bdays)` equates to `.format(key1=value, key2=value2,...)` where the keys are the names and the values are the birthdays.

So for that to work, your print statement needs to become -

```
print('\n {Wesley Neill} \n {Victoria Neill} \n {Heather Neill}'.format(**bdays))
```

That will print the bdays for those 3 people.

Try the following in your python console -

```
>>> [*bdays]
['Wesley Neill', 'Victoria Neill', 'Heather Neill']
```